# renewal measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, renewal-processes

I deal with renewal processes and do not understand the concept of the measure of a renewal process. Our professor has defined the measure of a renewal process as follows:

$$U (t) = 1_{t \geq 0} + E[N_t] $$

$N(t)$ is defined as the number of renewals untill time $t$

However, a measure should fulfil the characteristic that the measure of the empty set is zero. As we defined $U (t)$, it’s always at least one, so it can’t be a measure. Or do I have a mistake in my thinking?

I need to understand this definition to deal with renewal equations. Renewal measure is a kind of prelimeries in the notes of my Professor.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me this measure of renewal processes. Maybe by way of an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U(t)$ is a non-decreasing right continuous function and basic measure theory tells us that there is a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu ([0,t])=U(t)$. It is this $\mu$ which is called the renewal measure.

Comment: But the condition that $\mu (\emptyset) = 0$ is hurt. So it could not be a measure. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Do you know that every CDF gives rise to a measure? This is basic to Probability Theory, The situation here is similar except that $U$ is not bounded so $\mu$ is not a finite measure. You are not defining the measure of a  set explicitly so you cannot write down the measure of empty set diretctly from the formula for $U(t)$. @Mufasa